# Eagle-how to change footprint?

Tags: eaglecad

I know its basic but google just doesn't give me anything .

I have `Eagle` on a mac, i have a design with a few resistors, i would like to change their footprint to `0805` .

The menu is just not showing me this option to see the part footprint.

thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify, in what way can't you see the footprint?

Comment: Well, i just dont know how to edit and see a component footprint, i mean , where is it in the software menus ?

Comment: Right lick on a component and go to open device. This will show the symbol and the package.

Comment: @vini_i Oh thanks thats working! post it as answer i will accept. its quite simple but its hidden and there is nothing on google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a component and go to open device. This will show the symbol and the package.

This only works with library parts that are in the lbr folder of the root eagle directory. If you have your own custom libraries you have to open the library directly.

Also when placing components using the add tool, it shows you a preview of both the symbol and the package.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using resistors from, say, the `resistors` or `rcl` libraries, the resistor part has multiple footprints already of all different shapes and size.

In this case all you need to do is right click on the part (either in layout or in the schematic), and click the option named `package`. This will bring up a window of all the available packages to choose from.

The context menu looks something like this:

[image: Context Menu]

And this is the window that appears:

[image: Package Window]

So in my case I was using an 0402, but can change it to one of many other sizes. Simply select the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to change the footprint of **multiple components** together.

Starting in **Eagle 9**, there are new tools available that simplify this task: **Design Manager** and **Inspector**

If they are not visible, enable them using the "View" menu.

Now follow these steps in "Browser" tab of **Design Manager**:

1. In "View" drop down menu, select "Devices".
2. In "Device Sets", make sure that "<All Devices>" is selected.
3. In "Devices" section, type in the footprint that you want to change. This will filter the device list so devices with matching footprint are shown.
4. In the device list, select all devices (click the first device and shift-click the last device in the list) or only a subset of them (ctrl-click on a list entry).

Now in **Inspector**:

In "Quick Actions", click on the second icon (from the left).
This will open the "REPLACE" window where you can select the new footprint to assign to the components you selected before.

See the screenshot for a graphical view of the workflow.

[image: Screenshot with annotations]

Hope that helps.